# Particular case of every sequence has a Cauchy subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis

A metric space (X,d) has the following property:

Given  $\epsilon >0$ and non-empty finite subset $X_\epsilon \subset X$

$$ \inf \{ d(x,p) : p \in X_\epsilon \} < \epsilon$$

for $x \in X$

I would like to prove every subsequence in X has a Cauchy subsequence.

I wonder if I can use Bolzano-Weirestrass theorem to prove it.

Is there an example this is not true when $X_\epsilon$ is not finite?

Here is my sketch of a proof:

Since $X_\epsilon$ is finite, it can be put in correspondence with a set whose elements are the integers $1, 2, \dots, n$. Therefore, $X_\epsilon$ is bounded.
The set $ \inf \{ d(x,p) : p \in X_\epsilon \} < \epsilon$ says all $x \in X$ will be $\epsilon$-closeto some point $p \in X_\epsilon$. Since $X_\epsilon$ is bounded then the sequence $\{ x_n\}$ of points $x\in X$ will be bounded.
Now, every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence.
Finally, every convergence subsequence is a Cauchy subsequence.

What do you guys think? Is this sketch of a proof acceptable?

Comment: what is lower case x?

Comment: x belongs to X. What do you think of my sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof works in $\mathbb{R}^n$ under the usual metric (from the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem), but fails in general. In particular, it conflates "bounded" with "compact", which is, in general, not true - for instance, in the space of countably many points with the discrete metric (i.e. where the distance between two distinct points is always exactly $1$), any sequence is bounded (always being less than $1$ from any chosen point), but if it never repeats a term, it never has a Cauchy subsequence. This is, more or less, an unavoidable problem with your proof, since, in general, it shows that establishing boundedness won't actually tell you much about the desired property (though it could serve as a counterexample to the property if $X_{\varepsilon}$ were allowed to be even countably infinite).

However, the property *is* true. You just need a better proof of it. What I'd do is to consider a sequence of sequences $S_{i,n}$, where $S_{0,n}$ is the original sequence. We can ensure the following properties:

- $S_{i+1,n}$ is a subsequence of $S_{i,n}$
- Aside from the first $i$ terms, all terms of $S_{i,n}$ are in a ball of radius $\frac{1}{i}$.

To do this, simply note that any sequence $S_{0,n}$ must have infinitely many terms within a ball of radius $1$ around some $x\in X_1$ (since there are infinitely many terms and only finitely many $X_1$, balls around which cover the space), thus, after the first term of $S_{0,n}$, we can delete every term $s\in S_{0,n}$ with $d(s,x)\geq 1$, ensuring every remaining term is within a ball of radius $1$. Moreover, is $S_{1,n}$, we could delete (keeping the first two terms), every term not with a ball of radius $1/2$ around some $x\in X_{1/2}$, the existence of such a ball with infinitely many terms being guaranteed similarly to before. We can continue this process indefinitely, and then the sequence $S_{n,n}$ is a subsequence of $S_{0,n}$, where every term, after the first $k$ is within a ball of radius $\frac{1}k$ and is hence Cauchy.

Comment: Thank you for your proof. For example, if the subset $X_\epsilon \subset X$ are not finite, the property is not true?! Can you give me an example that shows the claim is not true if we don't require $X_\epsilon \subset X$ to be finite?

Comment: Reread the first paragraph - the thing with the discrete space is an example of how, if $X_{\varepsilon}$ were allowed to be infinite, the statement fails. Also, notice that if we don't require $X_{\varepsilon}$ to be finite, and $X$ is countable, then there's no reason not to choose $X_{\varepsilon}=X$, which would imply "every metric space on countably many elements is sequentially compact", which is simply untrue (since, moreover, it implies "every metric space with a countable, dense set is compact" - so even $\mathbb{R}$ would be included there, which is a problem))