# Proving a complete and totally bounded metric space is compact.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm having trouble writing down the details of this proof formally.

> **Statement**: Suppose $(X, d)$ is a metric space that is *complete*, and *totally bounded* (i.e., for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ finitely many points $x_{i} \in X$, $i = 1, \dots, n$ such that $X = B(x_{1}, \epsilon) \cup \dots \cup B(x_{n},\epsilon) )$.  Prove that $X$ is *sequentially compact*.

Here is the idea of the proof:

Let $\{ y_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $X$.  We want to show we can find a convergent subsequence.  But the space is totally bounded, so for $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, we can find finitely many $x_{i} \in X$ ($i = 1, \dots, n $) such that $X = B(x_{1}, \frac{1}{2}) \cup \dots \cup B(x_{n},\frac{1}{2}) $.  Then infinitely many terms of $\{y_{n} \}$ appear in some $B(x_{i}, \frac{1}{2})$.

If we look at the subsequence of infinitely many terms from $\{y_{n} \}$ that appear in $B(x_{i}, 1)$, it's clear the distance between each two terms in this subsequence is less than $1$.  I'll call this subsequence $\{y_{n}^{(1)} \}$.

We can repeat this process with $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2^{2}}$, that is, find finitely many open balls the union of which equals $X$, and one of these balls contains infinitely many terms of $\{ y_{n}^{(1)} \}$.  I'll call this subsequence $\{ y_{n}^{(2)} \}$, and clearly the distance between every two terms in this sequence is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

Doing this iteratively, I can then pick an element from each of these subsequences I am finding, and this will construct my Cauchy subsequence of the original sequence, which will converge by the completeness of the space.

It's clear that from this subsequence, the distance between two terms, say, $y_{n}^{(m)}$ and $y_{n}^{(p)}$ is less than $\frac{1}{2^{p}}$ if $p < m$.

So for each $\epsilon > 0$, all I need to do is find $N$ such that $\frac{1}{2^{N-1}} < \epsilon$.  Then $t, s \geq N$ implies $d(y_{n}^{(t)}, y_{n}^{(s)})< d(y_{n}^{(t)}, y_{n}^{(N)})+ d(y_{n}^{(N)}, y_{n}^{(s)}) < \frac{1}{2^{N}} + \frac{1}{2^{N}} < \frac{1}{2^{N - 1}} < \epsilon $.

Did I manage to keep all of the details straight?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: This statement might be made much easier if you begin with a statement (possibly from somewhere in your textbook) to the effect of "if a space $X$ is totally bounded, then every sequence has a Cauchy subsequence".

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I guess that's exactly the statement I am trying to prove, and this is where I'm hoping the details I wrote up above are straightened out.  The idea makes sense, but did I write it up in an acceptable way formally?

Comment: Honestly, I thought I should just put that down before diving into your proof.  Sorry if it's redundant.

Comment: You indeed seem to have the right idea! I'll try to nitpick a bit, but your proof looks pretty solid at a first read.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Awesome, and thanks.  Nitpicking is more than welcome because for some reason, I don't like the little details I focused on and I'm worried I messed them up.

Comment: Hmmm, it's not exactly clear how you'd go about selecting your Cauchy sequence.  How about considering the subsequence $\{x_n^{(n)}\}$?

Comment: Also, there's another approach that I find simpler, if you're interested.

Comment: I recently posted a proof of this same problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988998/particular-case-of-every-sequence-has-a-cauchy-subsequence/989919#989919), which is essentially the same as yours; it's phrased a little differently, so you might benefit from seeing it, even though you already clearly understand what the idea is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're proof seems mostly all right, though I find it hard to follow towards the end.  If I were to write a proof along the same lines, I would write it as follows:

---

Let $\{ y_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $X$.  $X$ is totally bounded, so we can find finitely many $x_{i} \in X$ ($i = 1, \dots, n $) such that $X = B(x_{1}, \frac{1}{2}) \cup \dots \cup B(x_{n},\frac{1}{2})$.

We note that infinitely many terms of $\{y_{n} \}$ must appear in some ball $B(x_{i}, \frac{1}{2})$.  Define $\{y_{n}^{(1)}\}$ to be the subsequence of terms that appear in this ball.

If we look at the subsequence of infinitely many terms from $\{y_{n} \}$ that appear in $B(x_{i}, 1)$, it's clear the distance between each two terms in this subsequence is less than $1$.  I'll call this subsequence $\{y_{n}^{(1)} \}$.

In fact, we can repeat this process in the following way: for any integer $k > 1$, we may select a ball $B$ of radius $1/2^k$ containing infinitely many elements of $\{y^{(k-1)}\}$.  Define $\{y_{n}^{(k)}\}$ to be the subsequence whose elements are the elements of $\{y_{n}^{(k-1)}\}$ that fall in $B$.

Now, consider the subsequence of $y_n$ given by $x_n = y_n^{(n)}$.  We note that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we may select an $N$ such that $1/2^{N} < \epsilon$.  For $n>m>N$, we note that $x_n,x_m$ are both elements of the sequence $\{y_n^{(N)}\}$, which means that both are elements of a ball of radius $1/2^N$.  Thus, we may state that
$$
d(x_n,x_m) < 1/2^N < \epsilon
$$
Thus, $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy subsequence of $\{y_n\}$.  Since $X$ is compact, $\{x\}_n$ converges.

Thus, every sequence in $X$ has a convergent subsequence, which is to say that $X$ is sequentially compact.

Comment: I feel like it is important to specify where you are extracting future subsequences from when you say "we can repeat this problem in the following way.  Are you extracting the new subsequence from the last subsequence you found at each step, or from the original sequence?  I feel like the former should be the correct answer, assuming it makes a difference at all.

Comment: "whose elements are the elements of $\{y_{n}^{(k-1)}\}$ that fall in $B$": $\{y_{n}^{(k-1)}\}$ is the subsequence from the previous step. So I did go with the former.

Comment: Ooh I see.  Also, I would be interested in seeing the alternate proof you mentioned.

Comment: Ah, the other idea wouldn't work anyway, upon further thought.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is entirely correct, but it’s a bit sloppy in spots. I would do something like this.

> Since $X$ is totally bounded, there are an $x_0\in X$ and an infinite $N_0\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that $y_n\in B(x_0,1)$ for all $n\in N_0$. Given an infinite $N_k\subseteq\Bbb N$ and an $x_k\in X$ such that $y_n\in B(x_k,2^{-k})$ for all $n\in N_k$, total boundedness of $X$ implies that there are an $x_{k+1}\in X$ and an infinite $N_{k+1}\subseteq N_k$ such that $y_n\in B(x_{k+1},2^{-(k+1)})$ for all $n\in N_{k+1}$. Now let $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be an increasing sequence in $\Bbb N$ such that $n_k\in N_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. Then $\langle y_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, and $y_{n_k}\in B(x_\ell,2^{-\ell})$ whenever $\ell\le k$. In particular, whenever $k,\ell>m$ we have $$d(y_{n_k},y_{n_\ell})\le d(y_{n_k},x_{m+1})+d(x_{m+1},y_{n_\ell})<2\cdot2^{-(m+1)}=2^{-m}\;,$$ so $\langle y_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is Cauchy and therefore converges, since $X$ is complete. $\dashv$

You can add more detail to the application of total boundedness if you feel that it’s necessary.

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot: You’re welcome!